# How do i know if resource deploy incrementally with Azure CLI deployment via Devops CI/CD Piplines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, cicd

I was wondering if there is a way to know, see and confirm that deploying recourses using Azure CLI files in Devops CI/CD pipelines deploy the defined resources and options incrementally?

I know doing so using Arm templates can be set as an option in the pipeline task:

[image]

But I haven't found anything similar in regard to Azure CLI deployment.

Comment: As @Roderick shared https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes#incremental-mode
Pease check If it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the deployment mode in azure cli with the `--mode` parameter.

For example for `Complete` deployment mode:

```
az deployment group create \
  --mode Complete \
  --name ExampleDeployment \
  --resource-group ExampleResourceGroup \
  --template-file storage.json
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes#set-deployment-mode) for details.

Comment: Aahh Perfect, thank you very much. but is this only for the resourcegroup or all the underlying resources too? or does --mode have to be assigned to each resource too in the CLI file? :)

Comment: In Azure ARM or Bicep a deployment has a certain _scope_. In my example the _scope_ is `resourcegroup` indicated by the `group` in the deployment command. Different scopes are `subscription`, `managementgroup` and `tenant`. Each scope comes with its own capabuilities. Resources themselves are typically deployed at resourcegroup scope. The mode is specified for a deployment as such. And that deployment may contain one or more resources. A `complete` deployment at rg- scope will ensure that the scoped RG looks exaclty like your deployment and any extra resources are thus deleted.